# Autorun command on startup of Raspbian

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, init.d, autorun

I have a Raspberry pi 2 B that is running Pixel raspbian. I need it to autorun the following command on startup, which will open an HTML file in chromium:

```
chromium-browser /home/pi/Desktop/IoT/Pusher.html
```

I've tried adding this into my /etc/init.d/rc.local,  /etc/rc.local, and .bashrc. None of them worked. However, when it was added to my .bashrc, the command ran, but only after I opened a terminal window.

Comment: give a try to a supervisor for example https://immortal.run/ it will help to keep the app up and running forever

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50520948/4902099

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww I disagree with your assessment. This question has to do with editing an OS boot sequence, which deals with software and coding the OS boot sequence. Since Stack Exchange deals with software questions, I must dissent from categorization.

Comment: But why aren't the methods I've tried working? @hcheung

Comment: It not working sometime because some of the services are simply not load yet during the boot when `rc.local` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Pixel, but you can have a look to systemd startup scripts.

you can find a sample here : https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/autostart/systemd/

regards