# Raspberry Pi Stretch startup script returning blank

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I have an RPi 3b with Stretch installed. I'm generating and sending a message when the Pi boots about external IP / internal IP/ SSID it's connected with.

I have a script with a command that does these things, and this line to construct the message as JSON works fine when run as the pi user or even as root after sudo su -:

```
echo -e "{\"time\":\""$(date)"\",\"hostname\":\""$(hostname)"\", \"distro\":\""$(cat /etc/issue)"\",\"extip\":\""$(/usr/bin/curl ipecho.net/plain)"\",\"ssid\":\""$(/sbin/iwgetid -r)"\",\"lanip\":\""$(/bin/hostname -I)"\"}" > /home/pi/hostinfo.txt
```

This script works fine when I run it locally ( shows where the values I expect are there):

```
    {"time":"Sat Sep 29 17:12:31 EDT 2018","hostname":"<expected hostname>", "distro":"Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 
 \l","extip":"<expected external IP>","ssid":"<expected SSID>","lanip":"<expected LAN IP>"}
```

I'm trying to run this at startup and the command runs fine and sends the message, but the last three values are blank:

> -e {"time":"Sat Sep 29 17:12:31 EDT 2018","hostname":"",
>   "distro":"Raspbian GNU/Linux 9   \l","extip":"","ssid":"","lanip":""}

I've added the script call to both rc.local and crontab (not at the same time),

rc.local:

```
su pi -c '<path-to-script> > /home/pi/rpi-boot.log 2>&1'
```

crontab:

```
@reboot <path to script>
```

Either way, the script builds and delivers the message as expected and doesn't show any errors in rpi-boot.log, but when it's run by rc.local or crontab the first three values (date, hostname, distro) are reported correctly but the last three are blank.

I thought putting the full path to hostname, curl and IP would work, and they do when I run from an interactive shell but when run at startup they are returning blank.

Comment: See my reply on https://stackoverflow.com/a/50520948/4902099. I think you need to delay the execution of rc.local for a few seconds to wait for all the services are boot up.

Comment: That was it -  i added a sleep 30 and now the value is populated at boot. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: the link that I share was posted by me, so you can upvote or accept that one, as I don't want to create a duplicated answer.