# Mono App will not Run on Start Up on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: mono, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am aware this question has been asked here before but the solution did not work for me.

I originally put this into my rc.local:

```
mono /home/pi/MyFolder/app.exe
```

I have also tried the above with the full path to mono.

I have also put (both) into:

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Nothing happens on reboot (do not know how to capture boot-up errors as the desktop is loaded.

If I run my app from desktop it works.

Anything else I can try (U have tried lots of things already)?

My app uses the camera.

### Additional

Now that I found out where the logs are created when running rc.local I have an error message to work with:

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException:
>   The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI' threw an
>   exception. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Could not open display
>   (X-Server required. Check your DISPLAY environment variable)

I will look into this now and update accordingly.

Comment: See my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/50520948/4902099. I think when the rc.local run, the system has not fully loaded yet, Add a delay in the rc.local should fix the problem.

Comment: @hcheung Hi so sorry I should have deleted/answered my own question. Yes I did see your answer on my travels :) and whilst it made a lot of sense (and led me to my own solution) it did not work for me. I shall answer/post my solution. But thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Putting my startup line inside the rc.local did not work for me and I played around with the timers. I think it is because my app was doing many different things on different threads.

My solution was to edit this file:

```
sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

and put this line in:

```
@lxterminal -e /home/pi/MyApp.exe
```

This will launch a terminal window and then execute my app.

As I am running in kiosk mode the user will never see that terminal window.