# Python script located in rc.local on Raspbian is not getting started on startup

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian

This is my Python script (main.py):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import time

# ..... some file imports from the same folder .....

try:
    # .... Some setup code

    while True:
        if turnOffRequestHandler.turnOffIsRequested():
            break;
        time.sleep(1)

except BaseException as e:
    pass
finally:
    # ..... Some code to dispose resources
```

And the way I try to invoke it on each startup was to first edit rc.local to become similar to this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi
python3 /home/pi/Desktop/ProjectFolder/sample/main.py &
exit 0
```

and then make my python script executable by navigating to the containing directory and executing the following command:

```
chmod 755 main.py
```

And then, I expected after a reboot of the system to get my script running. I can not tell if it runs or not. What I can tell is that i**t is supposed to call some web endpoints**. I am now wondering if it actually got executed but the wifi just did not get connected yet.

How could I diagnose that? Because, when I try to execute manually (after the system booted up and Wifi got connected) like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /etc/rc.local
```

it is getting it started and everything works as expected.

**EDIT:** Is it possible to be something related to the fact that the script that I try to execute makes a reference inside of it to files which are located in the same folder (which is different than /etc/..)?.

Comment: If you are script is working when running manually but not working when running as rc.local, other than file permission issue, the chances are that some of the services simply not available yet when the script is run. This can be solved by introducing a slight delay before running the python script. See my answer on another [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50520948/4902099)

Comment: Is it possible to be something related to the fact that the script that I try to execute makes a reference inside of it to files which are located in the same folder (which is different than /etc/..)?

Answer (score 0):

I would try simple bash script with 'echo "something" >> to_file'.

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect your output (like print "something") to a file while using the script.
change your script like this:

```
python3 /home/pi/Desktop/ProjectFolder/sample/main.py &> logfile.txt
```

and in your file use normal print to print in your file with 1 problem.
you have to flush the output while your code is running in order to see output file:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

**edit**

if you are using python 3.3 or above, there is an alternaive approach - print has argument to flush the output.